# Can a nodejs application can have two package.json files and can they be ran seperatly?

Tags: node.js

I have a nodejs app with the following structure

```
app
-dir1
-dir2
-dir3
app.js
package.js
```

and for `dir1` is an app of its own, also it will function as a package of the main app when ran from `app/app.js`

if i copy the entire `app` dir to another folder, navigate to `app/dir1`
it will contain

```
dir1
-pack1
-pack2
-pack3
-pack4
app_sub.js
package.json
```

and i have to run this `app_sub.js`

when i run this `file module not found error` is occurring

for the file in

`/home/mypath/app/dir2/somefile.js`

the error is occurring from  outside the folder of the app.

can you guys help me in this matter?

Note:

in the directory where i copied the app if i run the npm install from `app` directory and then goto the app/dir1 and run `node app_sub.js` it is working fine

Comment: The primary root folder only has one `package.json`, and `package-lock.json` file should have!

Comment: its there, for both app and dir folder